# Listview not scrollable after using expanded

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

i have a listview.builder which is refusing to be scrollable i found a few to be solutions on the internet but none of them worked out, i tried using an expanded() but that didnt help at all, the only thing i want it to be is scrollable. even tried

```
 physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

but this was also no help i have no clue what im doing that makes the listview unscrollable

heres the code: main.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: customAppBar(),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [
                bgColorFront,
                bgColorEnd,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
              child: Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder<Champions>(
                  future: getChampions(), // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Champions> snapshotChamps) {
                    if (snapshotChamps.hasData) {
                      return ListView(
                        children: [
                          TextField(
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              filterSearchResults(value);
                            },
                            inputFormatters: [
                              UpperCaseTextFormatter(),
                            ],
                            controller: editingController,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: customColorGray,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: customColorGold, width: 1.0),
                              ),
                              labelText: 'Champion',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: customColorGray,
                                fontFamily: 'Spiegel',
                                fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                              hintText: 'Fill in your champion here',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: customColorGray,
                                fontFamily: 'Spiegel',
                                fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
                            maxLines: null,
                          ),
                          ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: items.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  '${capitalize(items[index])}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SummonerMasteryRoute(
                                        snapshotChamps.data!.data["${capitalize(items[index])}"]!.key, capitalize(items[index]),
                                        summonerId, snapshotChamps.data!.data["${capitalize(items[index])}"]!.image.full
                                    )),
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    } else if (snapshotChamps.hasError) {
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshotChamps.error}');
                    } else {
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: 60,
                        height: 60,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              )
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
```

Comment: Try to replace the first `ListView` with `Column`, and then wrap the second `ListView` with `Expanded`

Comment: @AnteBule it worked thx alot, dwelled too long on this easy question sadly